# what information can i get from the client browser an how can i get that in laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel, request, client

I'm trying to save the most info about a client browser with laravel, actually i know i can access to the ip, the user agent and the request type, there is more information about the client?

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function example(Request $request)
{
    $request->ajax();
    $request->pjax();
    $request->ip();
    $request->ips();
    $request->userAgent();
    $request->fingerprint();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can dump the `$_SERVER` global variable and see the interesting values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information about the client is in the $_SERVER variable.

If you want the client browser use : `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

You can find all the keys of this dictionary here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful to my requirements, just i have a curious question, why in french?

Comment: Sorry, it was by default because of my browser